# Javascript counting not working: doubling instead of adding up

Tags: javascript

See my example. The script should set the variable to zero, and after that add up 1 every second. Instead, the value is doubled every second. Anyone have an idea what goes wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/kdKyz/

```
<script>
function count_it()
  {
    window.counts = window.counts+1;
    $('.result').html(window.counts);
    window.setInterval(count_it, 1000);
  }
$('document').ready(function(){
  window.counts = 0;
  count_it();      
});
</script>
```

Comment: I once used similar code to crash browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`count_it()` keeps calling `setInterval()` with itself as the argument and therefore keeps doubling the value. You need to replace `count_it()` in `ready()` with `window.setInterval(count_it, 1000)` and remove `window.setInterval(count_it, 1000)` from `count_it()`.

Comment: And also remove that same line from the count_it() function itself

Comment: Thank you, that seems to solve it :-). Will accept your answer as soon as i'm allowed!

Answer (score 1):

[`setInterval()`](http://www.javascripture.com/Window#setInterval) calls the passed in function every 1000 ms until you call [`clearInterval()`](http://www.javascripture.com/Window#clearInterval).  Your options are to switch to [`setTimeout()`](http://www.javascripture.com/Window#setTimeout) which will only call the passed in function once for each time you call `setTimeout()` or to do the `setInterval()` call once in the `ready` function (and remove the call from `count_it`).